# json path of the selected element from open api generated model

Tags: spring-boot, jsonpath, openapi-generator

It's a spring boot application, basically, need to iterate each element of the json and do some custom validation and while throwing back the error, need to specify the path of the element. To achieve this, we did the following

- API contract had been defined as yaml
- using open api code generator, generating model class w.r.t the API contract yaml file
- Sample Json

  {
  "employee": {
  "personal": {
  "name": "david",
  "age": "32"
  },
  "employmenthistory": [
  {
  "companyname": "xyz corporation"
  },
  {
  "companyname": "abc solution pvt ltd"
  }
  ]
  }
  }
- Generated Model Class structure like the below

  public class Employee {

  ```
   Personal personal;

   List<EmploymentHistory> employmentHistories;
  ```

  }
- Now, I am doing the validation, whether the given company is blacklisted company. E.g., xyz corporation is blacklisted company. So I need to throw validation error with the field name like this "$.employee.employmenthistory[0].companyname"

  One way of achieving is, manually I need to write some logic to construct this path and throw the validation error. Do we have any library to support this behaviour. I have tried with JsonPath Library, but it solves the other way around, i.e., if I specify this path "$.employee.employmenthistory[0].companyname" it will give respective value. Can someone help me to guide on this problem.

Comment: If you're using OpenAPI, then you're likely using JSON Schema.  JSON Schema uses JSON Pointers, not JSON Path.  The validator should be reporting errors with that. What's the schema?

Comment: Yes. It's uses JSON Schema. If the given JSON is invalid format, in that case, I can able to read the field path like this "$.employee.employmenthistory[0].companyname". But the specified above case is different, here the format is valid, but through custom java implementation, just doing the business validation and in this case, I can't able to get the path of the given field.

Comment: You've missed my point. JSON Schema uses JSON Pointers, not JSON Path.  If the implementation is giving JSON Path for errors, then it's wrong to do so.

Comment: If the data is valid, you're not likely to get any path/pointer information on any particular location unless the implementation uses the output specified by draft 2019-09 or later. It's sounding like yours doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Gregs! So to address this problem, if I am not wrong, need to write custom java implementation on preparing the json field path manually.?

Comment: Probably you will need some custom code, yes.

Comment: If you want a yes/no response when given a blacklisted company name you could `$.employee.employmenthistory[?(@.companyname == "xyz corporation")]`